# Sending the "Challenge friends" request in facebook Sdk using Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have created one app in facebook. In this app I want to challenge my friend. So that they can accept the challenge and play the game.
I want to know how can we approach to give "Challenge  Friend"

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make this Challenge as a Message or Thread? But as long as I know, facebook is updating this part of its API, so I think you can just wait for a few days and see whats going on?